# Problemas Netbeans conexión Base de Datos

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, netbeans-8.2

Mi problema es sencillo, pero aún no le he encontrado solución alguna. Cuando nos vamos a pestañas Services, nos salen las bases de datos, intento conectarme a la de "MySQL Server at localhost:3306". Pero por más que lo intento siempre me sale este error: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No tengo ningún código escrito, solo intento eso, conectarme a la base de datos.

Comment: te falla la cadena de conexion, mira si la tienes bien [aqui](https://www.connectionstrings.com/)

Comment: Suena estúpido pero... tienes la BD arrancada ?

Comment: Hola, la pregunta de @Capt.Teach es pertinente. Qué servidor de base de datos usas? En qué sistema operativo?, qué has instalado además de NetBeans? sin esa información imposible ayudarte.

Comment: La verdad es que no tengo muy claro a qué base de datos estoy intentando conectarme. Todas las rutas daban a esta dirección: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7.  Es la base de datos que me salía en Netbeans con el puerto 3306 en localhost. El sistema operativo es windows 10 y no tengo más cosas instaladas, ya que esto era para la realización de una tarea en la que debía instalar la base de datos de sakila habiéndome conectado a MySQL Server at localhost:3306